# Write Values That Are Present in Both Ranges

Tags: worksheet-function, conditional-formatting, vbscript

How do I coax excel into writing the values present in 2 ranges into another column? In the example below it would omit "q" because it's only present in one range.

`Column A   Column B   Desired Outcome`

```
y            y                y
z            z                z
q
```

Answer (score 1):

Using an if statement with 3 arguments

`=IF(logical test, result if test true, result if test false)`

in your example, cell C2 would be:

`=IF(A2=B2, A2, '')`

The empty string is necessary or you get `0` as the result if false

Comment: If there is any possibility that A and B can both be blank, they will pass the = test, but the blank will display as a zero instead of a blank.  If there's any chance that zero could be a legitimate A and B value, you couldn't just control it with formatting.  In that case, you could use a variant of the formula like: `=IF(OR(A2="",A2<>B2),"",A2)`.